# Restrict retail user

Tags: b2b

I want to have all my customers to register before they can see the prices and from the registration form they will have option to pick register as retail or wholesale customer. If they register as wholesale, they will have to wait on approval to grant access. If they register as retail they will be granted access to see retail price and check out. 
On approval for login as wholesaler they will be able to see the wholesale prices and use different shipping and payment method. Can someone please how do I accomplish this goal?

Answer (score 0):

I think your requirements are quite a lot and you may need some more modules to solve one by one. I am not sure about other solutions but by the way, I will suggest you some solutions for you to consider. Let's see the following details:

- "From the registration form they will have option to pick register as retail or wholesale customer. If they register as wholesale, they will have to wait on approval to grant access. If they register as retail they will be granted access to see retail price and check out":

=> For this goal, you can use [B2B registration](https://marketplace.magento.com/bsscommerce-b2b-registration.html) extension, which allows you to create a new registration form for only B2B customers, then you can also approve or disapprove customer registration manually. It is of course that you still enable another registration form (default) for normal customers (retails) and they can access without approval.

- "On approval for login as wholesaler they will be able to see the wholesale prices and use different shipping and payment method"

=> in this case, you need to separate shipping and payment method for each customer group. It means that your wholesaler will have their specific methods. You can consider to use this one: [Shipping & Payment method for customer group](https://marketplace.magento.com/bsscommerce-paymentshipping.html). I think it can be matched with your goal. 
Besides, you can force customer login to see prices with [Force login](https://marketplace.magento.com/bsscommerce-force-login.html) function or [Hide price](https://marketplace.magento.com/bsscommerce-advancedhideprice.html) function as well.

Comment: Thank you for your directions, but how do I achieve showing different pricing to different group, your solution only point to shipping and payment.  Is it easier to create different website or storeview and use the extension you mentioned?

Comment: You can set different pricing to different group in the Advanced pricing. It is default Magento function. This blog tells you how to do: https://www.customerparadigm.com/how-do-i-set-group-specific-product-pricing-to-a-customer-group-in-magento-2/